How to successfully deploy nested AWS Step Functions using CDK in TypeScript?
I am currently working with AWS CDK (latest version of aws-cdk-lib) to deploy nested Step Functions, where an outer state machine triggers an inner state machine. However, I'm encountering IAM permission errors with my current setup and have been unable to find examples or documentation specific to this scenario.
Here's the code snippet I've been experimenting with:
import * as sfn from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-stepfunctions';

// create outerStateMachine from definition
const outerStateMachine = new sfn.StateMachine(this, 'OuterStateMachine', {
      definitionBody: sfn.DefinitionBody.fromFile('location_of_osm_def_json'),
}); 

// innerStateMachine already exists, grant execute permission to outerStateMachine
innerStateMachine.grantExecution(
    outerStateMachine.role,
    'states:StartExecution',
    'states:StopExecution'
);

The errors vary depending on the modifications I make, but generally revolve around insufficient permissions.
Has anyone successfully implemented nested AWS Step Functions using CDK in TypeScript? I would appreciate any examples of working code or suggestions on how to correctly configure the IAM roles (using cdk) for such a deployment.

Could you add a sample of the specific error messages? It's difficult to help troubleshoot without knowing which permissions are required.

You can try to use the simple grant (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions.StateMachine.html#grantwbrexecutionidentity-actions).
If I understand the documentation correctly, the grantExecution grants you actions on the executions, not on the state machine.
